# How to declare and find a layout programmatically without using findViewById

Tags: android-studio, view, android-linearlayout

I have a layout and i am assigning an id to the layout then i find the view of the layout using id. is there a way a can find the layout directly and programmatically like using getBackground

My XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.RegisterFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_animation"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_first_name"
        android:hint="Enter first name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Declaring the layout and finding its view by id in activity

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
```

Declaring the layout and finding its view by id in fragment

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
```

Is the there a way i can directly get the layout background without using findViewById

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Do you mean that you won't be setting that layout for an `Activity` or `Fragment`, but you still want the background? Are you just asking how to load the `@drawable/gradient_animation` yourself, to get a `Drawable` without having to use the layout? Why exactly can't you use `findViewById()`?

Comment: when am using findViewById() i will have to assign an id to the layout, what am asking is whether it is possible to get the view of the linearlayout without setting an id to the xml and without using findViewById() and get the background of the linear layout

Comment: Yes, probably, but it kinda depends on how you're using the layout, exactly. If it's just in an `Activity` or `Fragment`, like you show in the last two snippets, then you could always `inflate()` the layout yourself, in both cases, and the `LinearLayout` would be the root `View`, so you wouldn't need `findViewById()` to get it.